# OpenNi Ogre3D integration using OpenGL

Tags: opengl, kinect, ogre3d, openni

I just started to use OpenNI and Ogre3D for an animation application. I found the below sample for this integration: [OpenNI Ogre Integration Sample](https://github.com/OpenNI/SampleAppSinbad). But I noticed that it is developed using DirectX which I am not familiar with. Are there other samples which are using OpenGL?

Answer (score 0):

Ogre actually abstracts away all the rendering code - it can use both DirectX and OpenGL (I've used it with both OpenGL and OpenGLES in the past). You usually have a dialog on start-up that lets you choose between OpenGL and DirectX on windows, and if there's no log file, there usually is some config file which specifies which renderer to use.

Also, all the other samples provided with OpenNI with draw to the screen use OpenGL with GLUT.

Answer (score 0):

This is the linux version of OpenNI Sinbad: https://github.com/ttair/TuxSinbad